# How does memory work in c# with variable assignment?

Tags: c#

I am working through some programming questions in preparation for interviews and I was confused by a solution that works.

The question itself does not matter, what matters is that in this solution one variable is set to that of another like:

```
ListNode current = head;
```

Then as the solution continues, this 'current' variable is modified. At no point does current get reassigned to head and yet it still returns head at the end with all the changes that had been made to current.

```
while (current != null && current.next != null) {
        if (current.next.val == current.val) {
            current.next = current.next.next;
        } else {
            current = current.next;
        }
}
return head;
```

Does this mean that when current is set to head, it is actually being set as a pointer to the memory address as head rather than duplicating the same properties?

I am very embarrassed by the fact that I do not understand what is happening here but i didn't feel comfortable just moving on unless I was confident I knew what was going on.

Thanks

Comment: not a pointer exactly, but a _reference_ to the same ListNode. think of your variable name as nothing but a scrap of paper with an address on it. two scraps with the same address point to the same data.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have. It is not clear what this code (or method) is supposed to do (and what it actually does).

Comment: Franz Gleichmann answered it perfectly, thanks! Sorry i didn't include the rest of the details about the code because I understood what is was doing, I just didnt understand why it worked since I didnt get refrences in C#. But after Franz left their reply I was able to do some research and I think I get it now!!

Comment: Make sure you understand how this code would behave very differently if `ListNode` were a **struct** versus a **class**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not pointer, Its reference in C#.

Yes, They will point to the same memory address. I am giving you one simple example below.

```
using System;
            
public class Program
{
    public class ABC {
    public int x;
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        ABC a = new ABC();
        a.x = 1;
        ABC b = a;
        b.x = 2;
        ABC c = b;
        c.x = 3;
        Console.WriteLine(a.x);
        Console.WriteLine(b.x);
        Console.WriteLine(b.x);
    }
}
```

It will print.

> 3
>
> 3
>
> 3

Comment: This was great thank you, is there any functional difference to using pointers or references? I understand pointers are used to point to the space in memory but I would assume for the most part this would be used just to you can alter the original variable like how passing by reference works in this example.

Comment: You can do everything with references which you can do with the pointer

Answer (score 0):

It's called copy-by-reference. C# has to object types: value types and reference types.

Creating an instance of an object allocates memory:

```
new MyClass();
```

Reference types are allocated on the heap, while value types (e.g. `int`, `struct`, `enum`) either on the stack or on the heap e.g. when defined as class member.
The reference to this allocated memory (the value) is also stored on the stack.

You can view variables and fields (and properties) as the reference.

As mentioned before C# knows reference types and value types. Both behave different the way they are referenced or their references are handled.

### Reference types

For reference types, *references* are always *copied* by default. Unlike C++ pointers C# references are not equal but point to the same memory object. This means every reference or variable is an individual object on the stack (unlike C++, where each pointer variable is actually an alias of the same pointer), but all copies point to the same memory object i.e memory location i.e. value.

Assigning the instance of a reference type to a variable/field/property *copies the reference* to the instance's allocated memory i.e. the value:

```
// Let local variable 'a' point to/reference instance of MyClass (the value)
var a = new MyClass();
```

Assigning a variable/field/property to another variable/field/property only *copies the reference* to the memory location *and not the value*:

```
// Let local variable 'a' point to/reference an instance of MyClass (the value)
var a = new MyClass();

// Let reference 'b' point to/reference the same instance/value/memory location of 'a' 
MyClass b = a;

bool areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(a, b); // true
```

For reference types, assigning a variable/field/property is like copying the actual pointer/reference. Since this reference is only a copy and not an alias, modifying one reference doesn't modify all existing references (unlike a pointer in C++):

```
// Let local variable 'a' point to/reference an instance of MyClass (the value)
var a = new MyClass();

// Let 'b' point to/reference the *same* instance/value/memory location of 'a' 
MyClass b = a;

bool areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(a, b); // true

// Let 'b' reference a second instance. 
// But 'a'  will still reference the first instance.
b = new MyClass();

areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(a, b); // false  

MyClass d = ChangeValue(a);
areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(a, d); // false  

private MyClass ChangeValue(MyClass c)
{
  // true (because 'c' is a copy 0f 'a')
  bool areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(a, c); 

  // Let 'c' point to a new memory location/value
  c = new MyClass();

  // false (because 'c' and 'a' are no longer pointing to the same memory/instance/value)
  areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(a, c);   
  return c;
}
```

When using `ref` or `out`, assigning a new reference to a variable/field will also override the original reference. When using `ref`, `out` or `in` references are no longer treated as copies but as aliases (like a C++ pointer variable). Modifying an alias modifies every other existing alias of a reference:

```
// Let local variable 'a' point to/reference an instance of MyClass (the value)
var a = new MyClass();

// Let 'b' point to/reference the same instance/value/memory location of 'a' 
MyClass b = a;

bool areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(a, b); // true

// Let 'b' reference a second instance. But 'a'  will still reference the first instance.
b = new MyClass();

areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(a, b); // false  

MyClass d = ChangeValue(ref a);
areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(a, d); // true (because of 'ref')

// Parameter declared as ref
private MyClass ChangeValue(ref MyClass c)
{
  // true (because 'c' is a copy 0f 'a')
  bool areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(a, c); 

  // Let 'c' point to a new memory location/value.
  // Because of 'ref' 'c' is no longer a copy of 'a', 
  // but an alias (same reference).
  // Overwriting 'c'  will overwrite 'a' too.
  c = new MyClass();

  // true (because 'c' and 'a' are still pointing to the same memory.
  // Because of 'ref' 'c' is an alias of 'a').
  areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(a, c); // true
  return c;
}
```

### Value types

For value types, the *values* are always *copied* by default. This means opposed to reference types, where the reference to a value (memory location)  was copied, the value or memory location itself is copied:

```
// Create a new instance of a value type (struct in this case)
var p1 = new Point();

// Assign a copy of the value to a new reference
var p2 = p1;

// false (because both reference point to different memory locations) 
var areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(p1, p2); // false 

Point p4 = ChangeValue(ref p2);
areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(p2, p4); // false (because different memory location)

private MyClass ChangeValue(Point p3)
{
  // false (because 'p3' points to a different memory location than 'p2' - value is copied)
  bool areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(p3, p2); 

  // Let 'p3' point to a new memory location/value.
  p3 = new Point();

  // false (because 'p3' points to adifferent memory location than 'p2')
  areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(p2, p3); // true
  return p3;
}
```

Using 'ref', 'out' or 'in` will create a copy of the referenced value:

```
// Create a new instance of a value type (struct in this case)
var p1 = new Point(1, 1);

// Assign a copy of the value to a new reference
var p2 = p1;

// false (because both reference point to different memory locations) 
var areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(p1, p2); // false 

// But their data equals
var isEqual = p1 == p2; // true

Point p3 = ChangeValue(ref p2);
areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(p2, p3); // false (different memory)

areEqual = p2 == p3; // true (same value)

// Parameter declared as ref
private MyClass ChangeValue(ref Point p3)
{
  // false (because 'p3' and 'p2' point to different memory locations i.e. values)
  bool areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(p3, p2); 

  // Let 'p3' point to a new memory location/value.
  // Because of 'ref' overwriting 'p3'  will overwrite 'p2' too.
  // But since both are value types they actually reference a copy of the same value at different memory locations.
  p3 = new Point(5, 5);

  // false (because 'p3' and 'p2' are pointing to different memory.
  areEqual = object.ReferenceEquals(p2, p3); // true

  // Only the value/data was copied.
  areEqual = p2 == p3; // true

  return p3;
}
```